# How to customize resolution on Ubuntu virtual machine (VirtualBox) that parasitizes a Windows host machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution, screenresolution

I don't know if Ubuntu detects the available resolutions but I know that VirtualBox can resize depending on machine resolution. The ideal resolution would be 1900x980 but I tried others too (like 1792x960 and 1728x972) and nothing works. Please help, thanks!

[image: Trying to set custom resolution...]

Comment: Did you install VBOX Guest Extensions in Ubuntu?

Comment: No. Image doesn't autorun and executables don't work.

Comment: You need Guest Extensions for better resolution variability.

Comment: If the image does not have / allow Guest Extensions, then simply, you cannot do what you want.

Comment: You should install guest additions from the Ubuntu repositories. The package name should be something like `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`

Comment: Ok thank you all, I'll try more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now that I saw "View > Auto-resize Guest Display" on VirtualBox machine window (the "xrandr" confirmed it) but maybe it requires "VBoxGuestAdditions.iso" installation if just click view-auto don't work.

```
rher@u22:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 1 x 1, current 1920 x 977, maximum 8192 x 8192
Virtual1 connected primary 1920x977+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x977      60.00*+
   2560x1600     59.99  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     59.96  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x768      59.87  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
Virtual2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual7 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```